# Help with my DHT22 sensor and using GET request

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, temperature-sensor, http

For some reason using my DHT22 sensor I keep getting "NaN". I have tried using older versions of the DHT22 sensor library as suggested by a few of my searches, but it still doesn't fix the issue.

Also I can't get it to work with the GET request portion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Phant.h>
#include <ESP.h>

#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT22

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
const char* ssid = "Myyyyyyh";
const char* password = "Ixxxxx1";
const char* host = "script.google.com";

//*****example address
//https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyNsFc87GQmRP3GnWoTzK6/exec?tag=test&value=8
const String gardenchart = "/macros/s/AKfycbyNnWoTzK6/exec?";
const byte sleeptime = 1;
const byte NUM_FIELDS = 5;
const String fieldNames[NUM_FIELDS] = {"ghumidity", "gtemp", "light", "otemp", "wtemp"};
String fieldData[NUM_FIELDS];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }
  fieldData[0] = 1;
  postdata();
  ESP.deepSleep(sleeptime * 60 * 1000000, WAKE_RF_DEFAULT);
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);
}

void postdata() {
  fieldData[0] = dht.readHumidity();
  fieldData[1] = dht.readTemperature(true);
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect (host, httpPort)) {
    return;
  }
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_FIELDS; i++) {
    client.print("GET ");
    client.print(fieldNames[i]); client.print("&value=");
    client.print(fieldData[i]); client.print(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host:"); client.print(host);
    Serial.print(fieldNames[i] + fieldData[i]); delay(500);
  }
  client.println("Connection: close");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adafruit DHT library causes a shortcut on the signal line. That can be a problem for Arduino boards, but it is a big problem for the ESP8266.
Issue: [DHT init sequence wrong #48](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/issues/48)
I don't know what is a bigger problem, the shortcut in the code or Adafruit not fixing it.

Why do you mention the Arduino Uno with a label ?
For the "GET" you should find a good working example.

The DHT22 is not very good. There are better sensors with a normal I2C interface, for example the HTU21D-F or the BME-280. This is about a great test: [Hackaday: Humidity Sensor Shootout](http://hackaday.com/2017/01/03/humidity-sensor-shootout/). The BME-280 is the undisputed winner.

Comment: I'll look for a BMW, for the GET request it was working when I was using sparkfun's data hosting.  I am switching to posting to my Google sheet and that's when something isn't working quite right.